# How to recover Veracrypt encrypted Windows

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, veracrypt, help-files

I have a fully encrypted windows 10, I wanted to try Ubuntu and booted it from the USB stick then I just wanted to try it out or install it on the stick. Then I got to the point about LVM and Luks encryption, entered my password and then clicked on continue. And then I finally canceled it before it was supposed to be installed for the last step.
I canceled the whole thing and wanted to boot my WIndows normally again. Now windows doesn't boot anymore or I think I deleted it , only get the message Cant find boot device.
Please its so important, can I recover my Datas that are encrypted?

Comment: The best advice is to restore from backup.

Comment: Encryption is very dangerous - many posters on our site have lost their data this way. It should never be interrupted.

Comment: @harrymc It wouldn't have mattered, at all. The option to install with LVM+LUKS wipes the target drive immediately after confirmation. Windows was gone and because encrypted unrecoverable.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to try Ubuntu and booted it from the USB stick then I just wanted to try it out or install it on the stick.

The option "Try Ubuntu" opens a live session running from RAM. Ubuntu isn't installed at this point and no other changes are made to the drives.

You can start an installation from within the live session but you shouldn't if the only purpose is to try. But if you want to install it cannot be to the drive you're booting the live session from.

> I got to the point about LVM and Luks encryption, entered my password and then clicked on continue.

So you decide to install. At this point you should have had unallocated space for Ubuntu and that, in your case, would have to had been done from Windows with Windows tools.

From the moment you selected to proceed with the installation using LUKS, the target drive is wiped out, it doesn't matter that you later canceled the installation. **Yes, you deleted Windows** and there's no way to recover from that. You'll need to reinstall Windows and all the software and then recover your personal files from your backup (if you have any).

Comment: Even if the drive wasn’t encrypted data recovery would have been very difficult, since your Windows drive was encrypted, data recovery is impossible